# Allow fading of caption in Supersized plugin

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I am using the supersized JQuery plugin for a full screen slideshow. You can see a demo here: http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/slideshow/3.2/fade.html

I have modified the css by placing the caption overtop the image (positioned absolutely). Each time the slide changes, the caption hides and then shows again on top of the new slide. I am trying to make the caption **fade in and out** as they are needed, however, I cannot figure out how to change the js to work like this.

The part of the plugin that controls the caption is as follows:

```
// Update slide caption
if ($(vars.slide_caption).length){
    (api.getField('title')) ? $(vars.slide_caption).html(api.getField('title')) :      $(vars.slide_caption).html('');
}
```

Any idea how I can modify the behavior given this code?

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
if ($(vars.slide_caption).length){
  (api.getField('title')) ? 
  $(vars.slide_caption).fadeOut("slow", function(){
    $(this).html(api.getField("title")).fadeIn("slow")
  }) :
  $(vars.slide_caption).fadeOut().html('');
}
```

Basically, if there's a new caption, you fade the old one out, and as a callback you replace it with the new caption and fade it in again. If there isn't a new caption you just fade it out before removing the old caption. You can of course use other speeds than "slow."